# Have the police forces in other countries besides India dressed in coronavirus costumes as an awareness campaign?

Tags: covid-19, comparative-politics, police, public-health, rhetoric

CNN etc. [have](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/04/28/india/india-coronavirus-outbreak-explained-intl-hnk/index.html) pictures of Indian police forces in coronavirus costumes, as part of an awareness campaign

[image]

Have other countries used similar in-person costumes for awareness campaigns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in [Bolivia](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/weird-news/police-encourage-social-distancing-dressing-21799867):

> A police force has come up with a unique way of reminding citizens of
>   the importance of social distancing -dressing up as the coronavirus
>   itself. In bizarre footage shared earlier this week, two uniformed
>   officers disguised themselves as the deadly virus

[image]

And [Indonesia](https://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/commentary/is-indonesia-doing-enough-to-fight-covid-19-12614440):

> An Indonesian police officer wearing a COVID-19 themed helmet conducts
>   a campaign and disinfects motorists' vehicles in Mojokerto, East Java
>   on Apr 3, 2020.

[image]